# How to design INT of 16,32, 64 bytes or even bigger in C++

Tags: c++

As a beginner, I know we can use an `ARRAY` to store larger numbers if required, but I want to have a `16 bytes` `INT` data type in c++ on which I can perform all arithmetic operations as performed on basic data types like `INT` or `FLOAT`

So can we in effect increase, default data types size as desired, like `int` of 64 bytes or `double` of 120 bytes, not directly on basic data type but in effect which is the same as of increasing capacity of datatypes.

Is this even possible, if yes then how and if not then what are completely different ways to achieve the same?

Comment: 16 bits and 32 bits, `std::int16_t` and `std:int32_t`

Comment: You need to use a big math library. 16 or 32 bytes not that big of a deal with a properly written library.

Comment: at @asynts the word 'exact' in the question has me lean towards std::int32_t

Comment: Then `struct int128_t { std::array<std::int8_t, 16> bytes; }`

Comment: ***Is this even possible*** The answer to your question is YES. There exist big math libraries that work with `c++` that handle arbitrarily large integers and floating point types. Some of these are limited to the amount of ram you have. https://gmplib.org/ is one such library.

Comment: @drescherjm yeah but I'm not sure how these big math libraries implement this stuff, could you explain it how to do so maybe or a pointer in the direction.

Comment: ***I'm not sure how these big math libraries implement this stuff*** At the simplest level you can implement such operations in the same manner as you learned in grade school. What I mean is how would you add, multiply ... using pen and paper.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  "can we in effect increase, default data types size as desired"  No, if you think 'default' means that your compiler will be able to handle the new bigger object.  On the other hand, you CAN create a UDT (user defined type) of any size, and define and implement the arithmetic operators you wish it to provide.

Comment: @2785528 not very sure how to implement all arithmetic operators, if possible show some examples on how to do so. Also, default is just used to say the size of primitive data type sizes in an architecture.

Comment: I think you need to do more research.  drescherjm has suggested the 'pen and paper' idea, which I understand, but have never done.  Note: I like gmp, and have no reason to look further into other implementations (as yet).  With gmp, an integer is declared as "mpz_class N;", and the factorial  12,345 ! is trivially computed in less than one second, with a 45,151 char result.  It makes large integer arithmetic fun.  I find the gmp implementation details sufficiently difficult (and c-style?) to discourage me.

Comment: The built-in data types correspond to operations for which the processor has built-in hardware circuits, for example 32-bit integer arithmetic, or double-precision floating-point arithmetic.  Defining a type of a different size will not change the hardware of your processor, thus you have to break up operations on your "32 byte" integer into smaller operations which the processor is capable of, paying close attention to behavior where you break the number apart, because carries and borrows may cross between partitions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, but no, it's not trivial.

First, I feel obliged to point out that this is one area where C and C++ really don't provide as much access to the hardware at the lowest level as you'd really like. In assembly language, you normally get a couple of features that make multiple-precision arithmetic quite a bit easier to implement. One is a carry flag. This tracks whether a previous addition generated a carry (or a previous subtraction a borrow). So to add two 12-bit numbers on a machine with 64-bit registers you'd typically write code on this general order:

```
; r0 contains the bottom 64-bits of the first operand
; r1 contains the upper 64 bits of the first operand
; r2 contains the lower 64 bits of the second operand
; r3 contains the upper 64 bits of the second operand
add r0, r2
adc r1, r3
```

Likewise, when you multiply two numbers, most processors generate the full answer in two separate registers, so when (for example) you multiply two 64-bit numbers, you get a 128-bit result.

In C and C++, however, we don't get that. One easy way to get around it is to work in smaller chunks. For example, if we want a 128-bit type on an implementation that provides 64-bit `long long` as its largest integer type, we can work in 32-bit chunks. When we're going to do an operation, we widen those to a `long long`, and do the operation on the `long long`. This way, when we add or multiply two 32-bit chunks, if the result is larger than 32 bits, we can still store it all in our 64-bit `long long`.

So, for addition life is pretty easy. We add the two lowest order words. We use a bitmask to get the bottom 32 bits and store them into the bottom 32 bits of the result. Then we take the upper 32 bits, and use them as a "carry" when we add the next 32 bits of the operands. Continue until we've added all 128 (or whatever) bits of operands and gotten our overall result.

Subtraction is pretty similar. In fact, we can do 2's complement on the second operand, then add to get our result.

Multiplication gets a little trickier. It's not always immediately obvious how we can carry out multiplication in smaller pieces. The usual is based on the distributive property. That is, we can take some large numbers A and B, and break them up into (a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>) and (b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>), where each a<sub>n</sub> and b<sub>n</sub> is a 32-bit chunk of the operand. Then we use the distributive property to turn that into:

a<sub>0</sub> * b<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>0</sub> * b<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>1</sub> * b<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub> * b<sub>1</sub>

This can be extended to an arbitrary number of "chunks", though if you're dealing with really large numbers there are much better ways (e.g., karatsuba).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define non-atomic big integers, you can use plain structs.

```
template <std::size_t size>
struct big_int {
    std::array<std::int8_t, size> bytes;
};

using int128_t = big_int<16>;
using int256_t = big_int<32>;
using int512_t = big_int<64>;

int main() {
    int128_t i128 = { 0 };
}
```

Comment: but then, the OP will also have to implement their [pronouns ftw!] own operator+, operator*, etc..

Comment: That won't help the OP perform the arithmetic operations that he says he wants to do.